# How to simulate "pinch out" gesture programmatically?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I am developing a iOS app.

I add an UIPinchGestureRecognizer to listen the pinch out action.

```
[[self view]addGestureRecognizer:[[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePinchOutGesture:)]];

-(void)handlePinchOutGesture:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        // Do something

    } else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        // Do something

    } else {
       // Do something

    }
}
```

However, I want to add an UITapGestureRecognizer as well so that it will have the same effect when user tap an item.

Is there a way to simulate "pinch out" gesture programmatically?

Comment: why try to simulate one gesture if you can just add both to the same view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's difficult to synthesize a touch (or multi touch) event on the iOS: you have to use non public APIs, so you have a high probability of getting rejected during Apple review.

Here's a link that demonstrates how to synthesize a touch event on the iPhone

http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/synthesizing-touch-event-on-iphone.html